# Dropdown Box that changes based on the option picked REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Opendota's API to populate a dropdown box. I'm trying to figure out a good way to go about 
updating the page based on what is selected in the drop down box. This is the barebones code I was using for it and was seeking some opinions on the best way to go about doing it. I was going to use react-router and onchange events but I think I may be overthinking it.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {hot} from "react-hot-loader"
import Heroes from "./components/Heroes";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Heroes heroes={this.state.heroes} />
        )
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            heroes: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let initialHeroes = [];
        fetch('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                initialHeroes = data.map((heroes) => {
                    return heroes
                });
                console.log(initialHeroes);
                this.setState({
                    heroes: initialHeroes,
                })
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }


}
```

Heroes.js

```
import React from "react"


const Heroes = ({heroes}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hero List</h1>
            <select name={heroes}>
                {heroes.map(hero =>
                    <option>{hero.localized_name}
                    </option>
                )};
            </select>
        </div>
    )
};
export default Heroes
```

Comment: Hi [4156](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11065180/4156), 
aren't you satified with my answer? 
Have you checked the provided fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Let App manage your state and select onChange:

```
    class App extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                heroes: [],
                selectedHero: null
            };
        }

        handleChange = selectedHero => this.setState({selectedHero});

         render() {
            const {selectedHero} = this.state;
            return (
               <>
                <Heroes selectedHero={selectedHero} heroes={this.state.heroes} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
                {selectedHero && <Hero selectedHero={selectedHero}/> 
               </>
            )
        }

const Heroes = ({heroes, handleChange, selectedHero}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hero List</h1>
            <select name={heroes} onChange={handleChange} value={selectedHero}>
                {heroes.map(hero =>
                    <option value={hero.value}>{hero.localized_name}
                    </option>
                )};
            </select>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: I'm assuming I will use onchange in Heroes to control everything else? It's starting to get confusing haha

Comment: Heroes is just a dumb component that take onchange callback from the App parent and triger it whenever change occured. The App component then handle the change and delegate the new state to a view component like Hero. this is how uni data flow model works in React. I suggest you read some docs from React.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the DropdownBox: you must pass the **onChange** event to the it like so:

```
<select name={heroes} onChange={onChange}>
```

In the **handelChange** you have to use the event to get the value of the selecte hero from it:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  const selectedHero = event.target.value 
  console.log(`selectedHero has changed to : ${selectedHero}`)
  this.setState({ selectedHero });
}
```

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/meziano/pen/JjopYVz)